# Multiple Address Autocomplete Fields? ( # Google Places API & getElementById # )

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API to add a field to my page where the address will automatically populate

It works when I only have 1 input field that I need to select by ID using `document.getElementById` but when I need 2 fields to autodisplay the menu to select an address based no the data entered into the field nothing at all works.

**The part of the script seems to be handled by below:**

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
/** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (document.getElementById('property-address')),
{types: ['geocode']});
```

**I have tried changing this to:**

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
/** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (document.querySelectorAll('#property-address, #property-address2')),
{types: ['geocode']});
```

After using the `document.querySelectorAll` none of the fields will work.

Is there another way to select multiple IDs or something I'm missing to get this working?

Below is the complete code in case theres something I missed in the script:

**Script:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#####API_KEY_GOES_HERE#####&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>

<script>
        var placeSearch, autocomplete;
        var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'long_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
        };

        function initAutocomplete() {
            // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical $(".classname")
            // location types.
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('property-address')),
                    {types: ['geocode']});

            // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
            // fields in the form.
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
        }

        function fillInAddress() {
            // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            for (var component in componentForm) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            // Get each component of the address from the place details
            // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }
        }

        // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
        // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
        function geolocate() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var geolocation = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: geolocation,
                        radius: position.coords.accuracy
                    });
                    autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                });
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to create multiple autocomplete objects.  There are several duplicates that demonstrates how to do that.

Comment: You can check the sample I gave here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803925/google-maps-api-retrieve-the-road-distance-between-2-coordinates/62892613#62892613